# Leveraging NEST for ES FunctionScore with variable number of functions

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Leveraging the 0.12 release of NEST I need to build in support via the function score API to have a variable number of function parameters in my c# application such as defined below.  Based on the current shape of the API I cannot find a way to conditionally add functions or pass a raw array of function items to the query descriptor objects.  Is there a different approach to accomplish this evident in 0.12?

```
bool useFunctionScoreForCreatedDate = true;
bool useFunctionScoreForAge = true;

var s = new SearchDescriptor<ExampleDataObject>().From(0).Size(10)
  .Query(aa => aa
   .FunctionScore(fs => fs
       .Query(qq => qq.MatchAll())
       .Functions(
        // need to conditionally add this function score to the FunctionScoreFunction[] if useFunctionScoreForCreatedDate
        f => f.Linear(x => x.createddate, d => d.Scale("0d")),
       // need to conditionally add this function score to the FunctionScoreFunction[] if useFunctionScoreForAge
        f => f.Exp(x => x.age, d => d.Scale("0.5")),
        f => f.BoostFactor(2)
       )
      .ScoreMode(FunctionScoreMode.sum)
     )
).Fields(x => x.title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `.Functions()` method with `.FunctionScore()` accepts a `FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor<>` object. So you should be able to use something similar to the following...

```
 bool useFunctionScoreForCreatedDate = true;
 bool useFunctionScoreForAge = true;

 var fsFunctionsDescriptor = new FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ExampleDataObject();
 if (useFunctionsScoreForCreatedDate)
 {
      fsFunctionsDescriptor.Linear(x => x.createdate, d => d.Scale("0d"));
 }

 if (useFunctionScoreForAge) 
 {
      fsFunctionsDescriptor.Exp( x => x.age, d => d.Scale("0.5"));
 }
 fsFunctionsDescriptor.BoostFactor(2);

 var s = new SearchDescriptor<ExampleDataObject>().From(0).Size(10)
   .Query(aa => aa
   .FunctionScore(fs => fs
       .Query(qq => qq.MatchAll())
       .Functions(fsFunctionsDescriptor)
       .ScoreMode(FunctionScoreMode.sum)
     )
 ).Fields(x => x.title);
```

Comment: This was the approach I originally attempted and cannot get it to work with the single overload available.  This is the error message received: 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Nest.FunctionScoreFunctionsDescriptor<ExampleDataObject>' to 'Nest.FunctionScoreFunction<ExampleDataObject>'

The only available method I have are for the function descriptor params followed by the function[] which I cannot add to dynamically.